# No valid settings file could be found

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I've just installed QT Creator and I wanted to continue developing an old C++ UI application that I designed in 2015. The installation completed without any errors. But when I try to open project and browse to my .pro to load the project, I a pop-up info box appears with the following message:

> No valid settings file could be found.
>
> All settings files found in
> directory "/Users/.../workspace/appname/appname.pro.user" were
> unsuitable for the current version of Qt Creator.

what is the problem and how can I troubleshoot and fix it ?

Comment: remove `appname.pro.user` and open again

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you create a project and configure it for a particular kit .. that's stored in ( *.pro.user*) file .. Now that you installed Qt recently on PC, the Qt versions/kits are not same as what you configured in your earlier project .. Creator does not find that old configuration matching anything on new Qt environment .. so the message.
You can always delete that file ( *.pro.user*) without any problem, if you want to port your project to different Qt environment (like another PC .. another platform .. etc) and Creator will prompt you to select new configuration (Kits). and that won't affect your code , it would work as before as far as its compatible with new selected kit.

Comment: I experience this problem from simply copying the project to a flashdrive and then back to the same machine that produced the project. I've never updated Qt since I started using it so its definitely the same version. I had a lot of post build steps in there I can't seem to move from one .pro.user file to another.